# My time and date settings refuse to open (from the time indicator)

Tags: indicator

I'm not sure why, but since an update a few days ago, the time and date settings won't open. I would try to trouble shoot this myself, but I don't know the command for opening those settings offhand.

What can I do?

Comment: The command is indicator-datetime-preferences.

Comment: ty, I was able to fix the problem now :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem thanks to @elmicha's comment.
Turns out the application was running but not doing anything for some reason, so I ran `killall -9 indicator-datetime-preferences` and then `indicator-datetime-preferences` and it works :D!